# How to make searchbar corner round

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I am trying to make `searchBar` corner rounded. I have tried many ways of using `layer.cornerRadius`, `maskToBound = true`. I am loading the `searchBar` in the `navigationBar` programmatically. I have tried many solution given on stack-overflow but nothing worked.

```
func setupsearchbar()
{
    //      Setup the Search Controller
    searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = self as? UISearchResultsUpdating
    searchcontroller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchcontroller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search" 
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchcontroller.searchBar
    self.searchcontroller.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    self.searchcontroller.searchBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchcontroller.searchBar.delegate = self
}
```

Please help if there is anything I can do.

Answer (score 4):

Use following code which are working fine for me in my current project.

```
if let textfield = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {

    textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue

    if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

        // Background color
        backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // Rounded corner
        backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: @ShivamSrivastava, Pleasure to help you. Accept this answer, so it can be helpful to others.